# Definition of the word "Word"

Tags: meaning

word | Definition of word in English by Oxford Dictionaries
https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/word

Definition of word - a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing, used with others (or sometimes alone) to form a sentence and typically.

SO, if a word has more than one meaning, according to the Nationally accepted bible for definitions...can it be a word ?

A quote i read, "Words are used to disquise the truth, rather than uncover it.

What is so troubling to me, there is no consisent definition across Dictionaries. especially when in some definitions, words like..."Usually, could...etc to attempt in assisting to define which does more damage"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is under a misapprehension about the use of the word "single" in the single definition of "word" given in the question.

Comment: A single word can have many meanings just as a single book can have many chapters, pages, and words in it. Also, the longest word in your title should be spelled *definition*.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its a rant.

Comment: Robusto....thats not acceptable.....what is your source.....mispells happen to the best of us and worst

Comment: If you cant ans. the question with any intelligent input...Im not going to be upset is you find something else to do

Comment: "a single distinct meaningful element of speech or writing" means something like "gizmo" or "potato" rather than like "kdowmvi#" or "kl(,qodU".

Comment: Hot Licks..see the difficulity...(something like is used in your ans.  How do you know its something like....This is important to me. the more youlook into it, the issue expands

Comment: I think you're not willing to listen to the definition and try to understand it.

Answer (score 2):

When Isidore of Seville (560–636) was commissioned to write a dictionary of all knowledge, he was able to say that 'many philosophers asserted that all words had several meanings.' The technical term is *polysemy,* which came back [into fashion around 1950](http://ttps://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=polysemy) But since it almost goes without saying that words have multiple meaning, its use has declined.

> [polysemy](https://dictionary.com/polysemy/): the coexistence of many possible meanings for a word or phrase. (Dictionary .com)

In the definition of 'word' which you quote **single** qualifies **element.** You have treated it as if the phrase is "single meaning" which is a fragment of the adjectival phrase "single meaningful."
 There isn't a single, simple answer.  There are three major attempts to answer your question each representing a lifetime's work. Here are just three definitions of *word* from a question on LingisticsSE linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/27036/inventing-a-word.

> 1Words are basically what you'd find in a dictionary. Lance Pollard "Such as, calling them just "words", but that doesn't make sense." Why? 2 Words are just things you put spaces around ;) – curiousdannii "Words are just things you put spaces around" That's just one definition of a word and the worst one. That's the concept of a graphematic word which is useful when you want to count "words" of a text or are interested in spelling conventions. – tobiornottobi

You'll find many of the answers on that site are serious but not hard to understand.

Comment: Im looking for what the word means...not assumption and presumptions....Its ok not to know

Comment: Try https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/  There are three major attempts to answer your question each representing a lifetime's work.

Comment: Thank You, Ill pass. I shouldnt have to. Everybodys using all these (words) and nobody can give me a simple answer.  One thing cant mean two

Comment: @jamessydnor - Hugh has given you the answer as clearly as one can hope for:  In "single distinct meaningful element" you must take each blank-separated group of characters (ie, "word") separately.  It is a *single* element, not a group.  It is *distinct* -- separated in time or space from others.  It is *meaningful* -- has a generally understood meaning, for most readers/listeners.  If the *element* meets these criteria it's generally considered to be a "word".

Comment: When a question cant be answered, a member like Hot Licks will force you to accept his incompetence as authority.  Feel free to close it, because the questioned was answered in its inability to be answered. and that TRUTH does not have to be valudated by your ingnorance.  To highlight for future members Hot Licks's pitiful attempt to force what i should accept. refer to  Hot Licks 20 hours ago

Comment: The question cannot be resolved within the limitations you impose. There are a number of answers which are worth reading; some implicit, some explicit. There are also pot boilers, troublemakers and exploitations.